# Extract the second word of the files that start with the letter a in the current directory

Tags: linux, bash

Extract the third word of the files that start with the letter 'a' in the current directory. Script in linux.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a close question. That question was closed due to being unclear.  Consider updating that other question rather than posting an exact duplicate of it in a way that makes it not unclear and also so that it clearly explains why the given answers are not solving your issue.

Comment: open question other